# Best Api to unzip a file into memory

Tags: c++, qt, zip

I'm working on a Qt application where we have to read in zipped files or QByteArrays and unzip them in memory, reading the file contents without actually unzipping the file to disk.

Is there a good sdk that can enable this easily? We currently use QArchive (bugless), but we have found it to anything but bugless and are looking to move to a different solution.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Liron

Comment: Any reason why you cannot unzip to a temp directory? That is exactly the kind of thing temp directories are for.

Comment: How are these files compressed? Is only one file compressed at a time, or are you handling archives of files? It sounds like you're receiving compressed data from somewhere other than a file.

Comment: Have you looked at http://quazip.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: The archive has multiple files in it. We can't unzip into a temp directory because the zipped files are proprietary and we don't want other people to be able to read them easily. This leads to requirement #2 - if possible we want the archive to be able to handle passwords too.

Comment: quazip seems to be working just as we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up going with quazip. Thanks [Eugen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153861/eugen-constantin-dinca).
Seems to be working well.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) that is included in the contrib section of [zlib](http://zlib.net). It is very simple, but does the job well. More recent versions look like they handle passwords.

Comment: Minizip doesn't seem to unarchive files to memory. But since the source files are available, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to unzip to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html. It's licensed under public domain.

Comment: 7-Zip file manager has support for various formats using a variety of libraries, but the 7-Zip SDK (LZMA SDK) is for 7-zip's own format only.  The code for the other formats is not public domain.

Comment: Correct - we looked into this but it can't handle the zip format.