# How to unzip a zip file already loaded in memory in C?

Tags: c++, c, zip, unzip

I am writing a server, which receive a zip file from client, and unzip the file.
When I receiving the zip file, I store it into memory.

I find and try some library to upzip a zip file, such zlib and minizip, but all of them unzip a file exists on disk, not from memory.

I don't want to save the file into disk temperorily and extract it, it's not efficient.

How to unzip a file from memory?
I write C and C++ on Windows.

Comment: Please check answers to this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303741/best-api-to-unzip-a-file-into-memory.

Comment: I don't use Qt and quazip seems Qt specific.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [libarchive](http://libarchive.github.com/)
It supports the zip format.

Example of extracting archive in memory:

```
struct archive *a = archive_read_new();
archive_read_support_compression_gzip(a);
archive_read_support_format_tar(a);
r = archive_read_open_memory(a, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

Answer (score 3):

zlib supports in-memory inflate() and deflate() functions. You can read how from [here](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html)

Comment: @Celebi: what do you mean it doesn't support .zip format? it's created to handle zip format. if it doesn't work, check the header. probably even though the extension is .zip, the compression algorithm actually used is lzma or something else.

Comment: @LeleDumbo zlib's FAQ says it doesn't handle .zip archives. "See the directory contrib/minizip in the zlib distribution". but minizip handle .zip archives from file, not from memory.

Comment: @LeleDumbo: `zlib` supports the inflate/deflate compression algorithm, which is used in .zip files. But it doesn't do anything with .zip files themselves, something else needs to pull the various different deflated files out of the .zip file and run each one through zlib separately. If it helps, consider an analogy with media files: you have an encoding but you also have a container format. .zip files (aka PKZIP) is a container format.

Comment: @SteveJessop, zlib is just a compression library. For extracting .zip files, we need to write additional code. Can you help us with a simple/sample example? My project also needs a similar example. I need to read the zip file and read/extract the content of a particular file in memory.

Comment: @programmer: Raymond's answer to this question includes a link to a BSD-licensed program to do this. Look at that for example code to handle the PKZIP format. If it's too complicated, then "minizip" is probably simpler, search for that.

Answer (score 3):

libzip (which is based on zlib) has a function to open an archive from memory. Example code is [on github](https://github.com/aseprite/libzip/blob/master/examples/in-memory.c).

```
src = zip_source_buffer_create(data, size, 1, &error)
za = zip_open_from_source(src, 0, &error)
```